# Data folders for MonoGame project not included in published verision

Tags: visual-studio, monogame, publishing

I have the three folders marked in the image that I added to the debug and release folders to have game data such as tile map info. It all works fine and the game uses them when running through visual studio.

But when I publish the project through the option in VS's build dropdown menu, the published version doesn't have them, thus I get a game that runs, but had a character on a blank screen since there is no tile map.

What do I do to make these included and usable to the published version? I have them in that location because it seemed like the only place it could find them when running the project in visual studio.

[folders in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL3XN.png)

Comment: Are you using the build action of `copy always` for the files in the directories?

Comment: Yes, I am using cop always, and build action: content. Should the build action be something else?

Comment: Please research embedded resources. They exist in the executable itself. This is the most platform friendly approach.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.